# how to find the disk information from Java

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I want to write to multiple files at the same time using Java threads. Can I create files that are accessed(written into) by different disk heads, so that the IO contention can be reduced?

Comment: I highly doubt you'd be able to get that close to the metal with java that you can chose which disk head you want to move.

Comment: yep, disk scheduling is usually done by the OS

Comment: Chosing head is an hardware option, I think... in java you can not decide for heads as far as I know... But if you can seperate your harddisk into multiple drivers as you know how heads are located (no idea) you can write to multiple locations as you know...

Answer (score 2):

Java is a [High Level programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_programming_language) language, and provides easy to use libraries to handle most of the tasks. And most of the libraries are written by expertise with proven algorithms and logic.

So when you use Java, it already tries to select most efficient way to store the data at I/O hardware level.

if you really want to take control of the Hardware, then you need to do the programming in "[Low Level Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-level_programming_language)" languages such as C, C++ or assembly and access them from Java using the JNI. Of course, that's what JVM does for most of the I/O operations including the threads.